# <toHaveBeenCalled> : Expected a spy, but got undefined

Tags: javascript, extjs, jasmine, mocking

I am trying to test the functionality below in Ext4js

```
functionA: function {
   functionB();
}
```

This is what I am trying in my test:

```
beforeEach(function (){
   somePanel= mockControlItem(subject, 'parentPanel', ['functionB']);
}

it("will run function B when functionA runs", function() {
   spyOn(subject,'onIdChanged');
   expect(subject).toHaveListener('show', 'functionA');
   somePanel.functionB.and.returnValue(true);
   subject.functionA();
   expect(somePanel.functionB).toHaveBeenCalled();
}
```

I get an error: `toHaveBeenCalled> : Expected a spy, but got undefined.`

Comment: What does the `mockControlItem` function do?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the line

```
somePanel.functionB.and.returnValue(true);
```

for this one

```
spyOn(somePanel, 'functionB').and.returnValue(true);
```

[See the docs](https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.0/Spy.html)

Hope it helps